# Inserting a Timestamp into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, timestamp

**Hello everyone.**

I can't get it figured out, so if someone could help me; yes please!
Spend some hours searching now, but who cares, here is the question.

```
$enddate = time() + $packagesrow['length'];

if ($packagesrow['length'] != 0) mysql_query("INSERT INTO memberships (id_package,    id_user, enddate) VALUES ('$packageid', '$userid', '$enddate')");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchases (id_package, id_user) VALUES ('$packageid', '$userid')");
```

For some reason MySQL doesn't accept the '$enddate' variable, I did make sure it is just an int, by echoing it. But when I look inside of the MySQL database it will show "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (Which is the default value)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Your mysql column is of datetime data-type** use:

```
$enddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() + $packagesrow['length']));
```

Comment: The MySQL column is a 'timestamp' data-type. Should I change it you mean?

Comment: I re-checked, it is a timestamp... But your code did the job, it all works now, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your column **enddate** to timestamp data-type.